# Yet another problem of terminology about permutations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, permutations

I am looking for notations and ways to formalize applications/functions involving permutations.

Let a sequence of integers $1$, $2$, ... $n$. How to formalize, mathematically, a permutation that consists to randomly permute the $n-1$ first integers, letting unchanged the last one, $n$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maseap/teaching/aa/aanotes.pdf) (PDF) does an excellent job of going over the various notations for permutations.

In this case, you've already formalised it. However, what you're doing is choosing a random element of $S_{n-1}$, taking the (first) natural inclusion of $S_{n-1}$ in $S_n$, and taking the image of your random element under that inclusion (equivalently, you're choosing a random element of the stabiliser $\mathrm{Stab}_{S_n}(n)$ of $n$ inside $S_n$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link. So, the searched term is "stabiliser"? I have not found the term in the linked pdf.

Comment: The linked PDF doesn't take the stabiliser approach: it goes for the other one instead. Specifically: there's a map from $S_{n-1}$ to $S_n$ given by taken every permutation in $S_{n-1}$ and extending it to a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ by just leaving $n$ unchanged. You're simply selecting an element of $S_{n-1}$, then passing it through that map. Of course, the image of that map is isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$, so for most purposes, you might as well just stick to $S_{n-1}$.